# python: how to store dropdown selected value to python variable

Tags: python, html-select

I'm using `python2.7`, i want to store selected `dropdown` value to `python` variable. i filled dropdown with `database` values using below code:

```
import MySQLdb

def db_dropdown():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', db='test', passwd='test', host='ip-address')
    cursor = db.cursor()

    sql = 'SELECT username FROM emplist'
    cursor.execute(sql)
    list_tested = cursor.fetchall() 
    list_tested = [i for sub in list_tested for i in sub] 

    return list_tested

print "content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'

def print_dropdown(data):
    print '<div>'
    print '<select>'
    for i in data:
        print '<option value="%s">%s</option>' % (i, i)
    print '</select>'
    print '</div>'

print_dropdown(db_dropdown())

print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

with this code my `dropdown` is filled with database values. now i want to store selected `dropdown` value to `python` variable. how to do this..? is there any option in python..?

please help me......

Comment: You should create a form and put the dropdown inside the form and on form submit you can get dorpdown selected value in python code .

Comment: You want to make a form and collect the result. It is not only Python's work but also HTML's. You can use [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) to deal with the the latter

Comment: if i use form when i open my page it directly executes right and if i refresh webpage previous selected data's are not erased that data are still remain's in the variables.